# TextMate Haskell Bundle

Tags: haskell, textmate

I wonder that there is no Haskell TextMate Bundle. [Macromates.com](http://manual.macromates.com/en/bundles) says that there was a bundle but it seems that it doesn't exists anymore. Are there any other ways to get Haskell Syntax Highlighting on TextMate?

Comment: There has been a version on github for some time, but it seems the svn version was only killed in the last month http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.editors.textmate.devel/14457  as have several others; there is evidently some new policy at work.  (It's a strange idea, if they are keeping the svn respository for other things, since Haskell is the example the Manual uses for 'installing new bundles' via svn.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you've got git installed, go into terminal and enter

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Bundles/
git clone https://github.com/textmate/haskell.tmbundle.git
```

Then in TextMate, Bundles > Bundle Editor > Reload Bundles.

The syntax highlighter isn't perfect but usable. It gets confused on some comments and identifiers. I hacked it a little to fix it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked just fine. One thing though, maybe you should indicate this is ~/Library, not /Library.

Answer (score 6):

Seems like the Bundles location changed, so I did

```
cd /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Bundles
```

Apart from that I did as mentioned by Jason (git repo still works).

Or maybe I am wrong and you can just create that folder as in:

```
mkdir -p /Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Bundles
```

(did not try doing that though, but saw it on another installation instruction -git bundle-)

PS: I am new here and I could not find a way to comment on his post (maybe I don't have permission for that yet?)

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some work done [here](https://github.com/textmate/haskell.tmbundle) but I cannot confirm how well it works.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the zip from git:

https://github.com/textmate/haskell.tmbundle

Then I extracted it and renamed the folder to a `.tmbundle` (it had some numeric suffix).
Then I just opened it in Finder and it was recognised and imported.